# I can't "Create or Extend Web Application" in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I encounter this error **"Cannot find an unused port"** when I want to **create or extend web application** in Centeral Administration. I also tried to disable the antivirus and firewall but it didn't work.
The associated error with this in Event viewer is :

*"The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in Source ( PrmBackgroundAgent ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: system_monitor failed to run."*

If you have any idea, please let me know it ;)

P.S. I use Moss 2007 with SP2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/0d70c7a6-9ec5-4343-8f5c-29b9692c18d2

"As Lionel mentioned, Antivirus was the culprit.
To resolve the problem, you need to remove w3wp process from the list of internet browsers/internet interfacing applications list in the antivirus settings on the SharePoint server. Some of the Antivirus software have all the http safe port numbers listed in their settings. You might have to add you application port numbers in that list as well.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ping me, if you need any further details.

Sashi."

Comment: My anti-virus is Nod32. At first, I disabled the anti-virus but it didn't solve my problem but by using your method my problem is solved. Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the firewall or antivirus (asusming either or both are installed on the box)? There's a similar issue [reported on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/sharepointadmin/thread/0d70c7a6-9ec5-4343-8f5c-29b9692c18d2).

BTW, if this fixes it, obviously you need to locate the root cause (i.e. firewall rules) and not just run without a firewall or virus checker!

Comment: I have read that article on MSDN but it didn't help me, neither disabling both firewall and antivirus.
BTW, Thanks